# in ionic4 "BackgroundGeolocationConfig" Remove GPS Tracking Notification

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

in ionic 4 https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-geolocation
i implemented this , all working fine but "i want remove GPS Tracking Enabaled" notification when application goes background
Image attached [please view[image: please view]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47ACq.jpg)

```
  const config: BackgroundGeolocationConfig = {
    desiredAccuracy: 10,
    stationaryRadius: 20,
    distanceFilter: 30,
    debug: true, //  enable this hear sounds for background-geolocation life-cycle.
    stopOnTerminate: false, // enable this to clear background location settings when the app terminates
    notificationsEnabled: true,
    // startForeground: true,
  };

  this.backgroundGeolocation.configure(config)
    .then((location: BackgroundGeolocationResponse) => {

      alert(location);
      // IMPORTANT:  You must execute the finish method here to inform the native plugin that you're finished,
      // and the background-task may be completed.  You must do this regardless if your HTTP request is successful or not.
      // IF YOU DON'T, ios will CRASH YOUR APP for spending too much time in the background.
      this.backgroundGeolocation.finish(); // FOR IOS ONLY

    });

  // start recording location
  this.backgroundGeolocation.start();

  // If you wish to turn OFF background-tracking, call the #stop method.
  this.backgroundGeolocation.stop();
```

Answer (score 1):

try this in your

```
BackgroundGeolocation.config{
   notificationsEnabled: false,
}
```

Notification enabled false will hide your local notification. 
check this also: https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation#configureoptions-success-fail